# How to Set Opacity (Alpha) for layout background in Android?

Tags: android, opacity

Im use an image for my layout background is there any way to opaque it in xml?
I use `android:alpha="2"` but nothing happened!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
View backgroundImage = findViewById(R.id.background_image);
Drawable background = backgroundImage.getBackground();
background.setAlpha(80);
```

Comment: it is a layout background  not an imageView